# finding highest number, no arrays, only if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, numbers, highest

I am currently taking a course in Python programming and we have been given an assignment to complete of finding the highest number given by prompting a user.
This would be easy to complete with an array but we are unable to use them for this assignment.
I am having an issue where if I input a series of numbers such as "55, 100, 99" my program is telling my 99 is the highest number. I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
temp = None
while temp != "done":
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break
    try:
        int(num)
    except:
        print ('That is not an integer. Try again')
        break
    print(largest)
    if largest is None:
        largest = num 
    if largest != None and num > largest:
        largest = num
print ('Invalid input')
print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Comment: You need to convert `num` to an integer before you compare it with `largest`.

Comment: `int(num)` on its own does not do what I'm guessing you think it does. Try `type(num)` afterwards; surprised? Python is *strongly typed*, you can't cast in-place.

Comment: You are not assigning the conversion of `num` to `int` to any variable

Comment: You can also `if largest is  None or num > largest:`and forget the other if

Answer (score 1):

Change `int(num)` to `num = int(num)` to save type conversion

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
int(num)
```

to:

```
num = int(num)
```

Otherwise, `num` will still be a string because you're not saving the result of the conversion anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a **break** in the except suite. Reason being that the program quits upon execution of the code in the except suite. That said your type conversion from **string** to **int** is not being saved anywhere. To save this try this:

```
num= int(num) instead of just int(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in addition to saving int(num) to num, you don't need to check for largest/smallest is None each loop, rather just initialize it when the loop is first entered:

```
first=True
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break
    try:
        num = int(num)
    except:
        print ('That is not an integer. Try again')
        raise

    if first:
        largest = smallest = num
        first = False
    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num
print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Upon error you could also just raise the exception, rather than break out of loop only (this way it's more pythonic and does not print those Max/Min results).